# I want to add Bootstrap popover with content body

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to add Bootstrap popover with content body in which I want two links named-"Update Profile" and "Logout" in content body. And this Popover I want to apply on a whole div section (div width around 100px and height=70px). So can anyone please help me !! Thank you !!

```
//Main Row starts of div section where i want to apply popover
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <li><img class="rounded-circle img-responsive" src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/no-user-image.png" alt="image"  style="width: 40px; margin-left: 10px" > </li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm" style="margin-left: 35px">
    //second row starts in between a main row(of second column i.e just defined above with margin-left:35px ) 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm"><h4 class="small"> Amy Jackson </h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm"><h2 class="small" >amy@gmail.com</h2></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```